# How do I update commerce product display nodes based on SKU (of the referenced product)?

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce

I would like to update the product display nodes with taxonomy terms based on the SKU of the referenced product of each node. Is that possible, programmatically?

1. I know the SKU.
2. I need to find the product by the SKU of a product display.
   1.I update the taxonomy term of the product display accordingly.

I tried to use `EntityFieldQuery` without success.

If someone could possibly give me an idea on the best approach to do this in DrupalCommerce, or provide a link to the documentation I have missed, it is greatly appreciated. I have lost a day or two googling the wrong questions, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Although an old thread, for the benefit of others looking, this could be done easily using [views_bulk_operations (VBO)](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). No coding required.

- Install VBO.
- Create a View of product display nodes.
- Add a relationship to commerce product.
- Add a batch update operations field to the View.
- Enable the "Modify entity fields" option in the VBO field settings.
- Add an exposed filter for the product SKU
- Save
- Use the batch update operation to check and set the relevant taxonomy term reference field.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do this just fine using feeds and commerce feeds. The sku is commonly used as the unique id.